# Need to connect to old device that only support 2.4Ghz wifi

Tags: wi-fi

I have a router at home where I don't have access to settings as it is managed by the landlord. The router has the same SSID for 2.4Ghz and 5GHz.

I also have a wifi camera that I want to connect to that does not support 5Ghz Wifi. How can I disable 5GHz wifi completely on my phones? I can't seem to find any setting on either of my phones. The devices in question are Sony Xperia 5 II and Samsung S22.

I don't want to throw away a perfectly working camera just because it is not super modern.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Added:
I need to connect to the camera directly from my phone - when I open the camera app it says "Camera does not support 5Ghz Wifi, please connect your phone to 2.4 GHz Wifi". I believe, it is needed to setup the camera's Wifi connection or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the app is using this "obscure morse system"  to transmit initial set-up data to the camera via Wifi even if the camera is not yet connected to the Wifi. Usually the packet length of the encrypted Wifi packets is used to transmit the WPA2 key to the camera so that it can join the Wifi system (Warning: transmitting a secure Wifi key just obfuscated = more or less in clear text over a Wifi network is insecure and may be intercepted by others, revealing your WPA2 key).

To make this work the camera is sniffing for all surrounding (2.4GHz) Wifi networks. Therefore the used smartphone also has to use 2.4Ghz otherwise the camera will not be able to sniff the relevant data.

To solve your problem you would have to temporarily disable the 5GHz Wifi of your router. If that is not possible you can try to force your phone to use 2.4 GHz.
Some Android versions have a `WiFi Frequency Band` setting (see Wifi -> three vertical dots -> advanced). If your version has no such setting you can try to use pure physics:

Tha maximum range of 5GHz networks is, because of the frequency, smaller than those of 2.4Ghz networks. Thus if you increase the distance to your Wifi router or use other ways to decrease the signal strength, the phone should switch to 2.4 GHz. Make sure that the camera is placed half way between you and the router so tat it can sniff the WPA2 key and then connect to the Wifi.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I am going to try today to configure it using an old phone without 5 GHz band. I have not found in my phones which are S22 and Xperia 5 II how to disable 5 GHz Wifi, and I was certain I was doing something wrong. Now it seems the setting is not present in either.

Answer (score 1):

If both 2.4GHz and 5GHz WIFI are available, the camera will automatically connect to 2.4GHz.  It will not even attempt to connect to 5GHz as it does not have an antenna for it.  That is, it can't even see the signal.

You do not have to disable anything.

Comment: I need to connect to the camera directly - when I try the camera app it says "Camera does not support 5Ghz Wifi, please connect your phone to the 2.4 GHz Wifi". I believe, it is needed to setup the camera's Wifi connection or something. Sorry for the confusion. However, you gave me an idea - I can use an old phone with 2.4 Ghz wifi only and setup the camera and connect to it with any device afterwards. Thank you!